# Get the event response of script in WebView to the react native

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am using the html script for showing some module. Everthing was going perfect until I got no any response of the eventHandler. How can I get the response of the eventHandler in Web View.I am not getting any log of the onSuccess, onError or onClose methods. I am using react-native-webview. I tried using  window.postMessage('onSuccess'); and geting the value on onMessage

```
 this.khaltiUI = `<html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://khalti.com/static/khalti-checkout.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <script>

            var config = {
              // replace the publicKey with yours
              "publicKey": "test_public_key_dc74e0fd57cb46cd93832aee0a390234",
              "productIdentity": "1234567890",
              "productName": "Dragon",
              "productUrl": "http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons",
              "eventHandler": {
                onSuccess (payload) {
                  window.postMessage('onSuccess');
                  console.log(payload);
                },
                onError (error) {
                  window.postMessage('onError')
                  console.log(error);
                },
                onClose () {
                  window.postMessage('onClosed')
                  console.log('widget is closing');
                }
              }
            };

            var checkout = new KhaltiCheckout(config);

            checkout.show({amount: 1000, mobile: 9800000000});

          </script>
        </body>
        </html>`
```

And in the react-native webView component:

```
    <WebView
      source={{html: this.khaltiUI }}
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      scalesPageToFit={false}
      style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0}}
      onMessage={this.onMessage}
      startInLoadingState ={true}
    />

    onMessage(event){
     console.log('Hello');  //got no any response
     console.log(JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data));
     console.log(event.nativeEvent.data);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

this what I use for sending data from webview to react-native:

react:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default class App extends Component {

  _bridge(event) {
    if(event.nativeEvent.data == 'exit') {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        source={{ uri: "https://www.kende.com/" }}
        onMessage={event => { this._bridge(event); }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

html:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#exit').on('click', function(){
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("exit");
        });
    });
</script> 

<span id="exit">Exit</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To post data to a web page, first, you have to get the `ref` of `WebView`:

```
<WebView
   ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
   onMessage={this.onMessage}
   ...
/>
```

Then post a message like:

```
sendPostMessage() {
    console.log("Sending post message");
    this.webView.postMessage("Post message from react native");
}
```

Comment: I wanted to get the response "payload" value onSuccess. I got no luck. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Are you sure the `onSuccess` is getting executed? Maybe you can mock this using a dummy function?

Comment: Also, `window.postMessage` accepts only `string` as parameter

Comment: As per the docs,
onSuccess This method is called once a transaction is confirmed by a user. 
So, it must be called.

Comment: Sure, if you're confident that, that function is getting executed.